# How can I create a debian package that depends on a specific kernel

Tags: dependencies, deb

How would I add a specific kernel and headers to the depends section of a debian control file?

I am trying to compile a package the need specific kernel patches to work right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as the [new maintainer guide][1] says: Use package (= version) syntax to fix a certain version of a package. For kernels, the version name is even in the package name, so something like

```
Depends: linux-image-3.0.0-1-amd64
```

should suffice.

[1] http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/

Comment: Hmm funny the one place I did not look. Thanks.